# How to get RemoteConfig defaultValue inside firebase function?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-remote-config

I am writing a firebase function.

And in there, I need a default value.

And since I set up a Remote Config in Firebase, I try to use it inside my firebase function (to have one source of truth as for the default-values)

Using the following code to retrieve a remoteConfig-parameter, how can you convert it to a typescript number ?

```js
const remoteConfigTemplate = await admin.remoteConfig().getTemplate();

const defaultVal = remoteConfigTemplate.parameters["video_max_duration"].defaultValue

const actualValue = defaultVal.value;

const finalValue: number = Number(actualValue);
```

In the code above, I see that `defaultVal` is of type `RemoteConfigParameterValue?`. But how do I convert it to a number in typescript ??

I tried to cast the defaultValue but this does not work...

```js
const defaultVal = remoteConfigTemplate.parameters["video_max_duration"].defaultValue as ExplicitParameterValue
```

The error is `Cannot find name 'ExplicitParameterValue'.ts(2304)`

What is still wrong ?

Is there another way of getting a Firebase Remote Config defaultValue into a firebase function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultValue`returns a JSON object of Type `RemoteConfigParameterValue`

```
    type RemoteConfigParameterValue = ExplicitParameterValue|InAppDefaultValue; 
    interface ExplicitParameterValue { value: string };
```

You have to access the value field of this object:

```
    const defaultVal = (remoteConfigTemplate.parameters['video_max_duration']?.
      defaultValue as any).
      value as number
```